# How to prevent template errors on initially null-set variable?

Tags: angularjs, templates

Let's say I have a variable

```
$scope.variable=null;
```

in AngularJS in my controller. I'll do a `$http` request for some data and after the request returns I assign the actual data from the response to my variable, so that the variable looks like this:

```
$scope.variable={'data1':'example1','data2':'example2'};
```

I also have template that presents the data, e.g.

```
<span>{{ variable.data1 }}</span>
```

Before the `$http` request there is no `$scope.variable.data1` and therefore in the browser console I get an error. Even if I do

```
<span ng-cloak ng-if="variable!=null">{{ variable.data1 }}</span>
```

it seems that the browser tries to evaluate the expression.

Errors look e.g. like this:

> angular.js:3626 Error:  attribute width: Expected length, "{{ svgconfig.ca…"

in a case where I want to set properties of an `svg` element.

Is there a way to not have the errors occurs?

Comment: you can use {{variable?.data1}} with Question mark

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use below function to check whether your object empty or filled with data.

```
 <span ng-cloak ng-if="isEmpty(variable)">{{ variable.data1 }}</span>
  $scope.isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```